# How to short-circuit component creation and redirect in Vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

In a dashboard layout, I'm rendering different components based on which menu the user navigates to.
I have a parent component that contains a `<render-view>` inside a `<Suspense>`.

What happens is that some of the pages (components) require a rather large amounts of data. I'm using composition API and I was fetching the data inside the `<script setup>` part of the component:

```
<script setup>
const data = await fetch(...);
</script>
```

With a combination of `<Suspense>` and `<render-view>`, everything works fine: there's a loading screen, and once the request is done, the component is rendered.

However, I'm having trouble dealing with errors that may happen during this process. Let's say an error happened during the `fetch` call and I want to redirect the user to `/error`, something like this:

`await fetch().json().catch(e => { router.push("/error"); })`

The problem is that the `<script setup>` code continues to run despite the redirection, which causes a lot of errors that can be verified in devtools console.

I want stop everything and redirect, I don't want to attempt and run the rest of the code that depends on the data that could not be loaded.

I also tried to move all the data fetching to the router `beforeEnter`, but the problem was I couldn't get a loading spinner to show, the screen just remains white/blank/empty while `beforeEnter` is running, even if I first render the loading component before `beforeEach`, the result is the same.

I also thought about fetching all the data before the router redirects, but then I would have to store it somewhere else and then pass it along to the child component in `render-view`, which seems way too convoluted for this problem.

I also tried moving all JS logic in a single fetch, but the component `<template>` tries to render anyway after my redirection.

Any ideas on how to handle this?

Comment: Did you try to throw an error? This is how the rendering of a comp is prevented. Needs to be verified if an error is handled by the router's onError or suspense onErrorCaptured

Comment: Yeah, I did. The render function still executes and throws an error, even if I do something like 'throw redirectToError' on setup, the render function still runs, which means it is not halted. The workaround is to set a container element with a v-if to stop it, but just feels wrong. It should be cleaner.

Comment: It shouldn't work this way. How do you know render function runs and where is it defined? Probably you combined script setup with render function the wrong way. Try setup function instead of script setup because the latter is syntax sugar that works in undetermined way. Can you provide a way to reproduce? It could be achieved the other way, generally <Suspense> isn't  explicitly used with router because it handles it internally, so it would be equivalent to beforeEnter, and a spinner should have been implemented differently

Comment: I know because the devtools console shows it. I had to implement a <template v-if> to stop it, it was the only way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I managed to prevent the render function call was to wrap the entire template on a `v-if` directive and control it from the setup, like this:

```
<script setup>

const ready = ref(false);
const data = ref();

const response = await (await fetch(...)).json();

if (!response.data.errors) {
data.value = response.data;
ready.value = true;
}
else {
router.push(...);
}

</script>

<template>
<div v-if="ready">
...
</div>
</template>
```

Although Alexander's answer can work, the rendering is conditional on anything being loaded into `data` without any additional validation, and there's no need to an IIFE.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the code into an async IIFE:

```html
<script setup>

const data = reactive({});
// use this for the spinner
const loading = ref(true);

(async ()=>{

  try{
    Object.assign(data, await (await fetch(...)).json());
  }catch(error){
    router.push({path:'/error', params:{error}});
  }finally{
    loading.value = false;
  }

})();

</script>
```

In my project i use more complex but a generic solution with the routes' transform that would replace all route components with a generic loader component with a spinner which would resolve data from some `resolve()` function in a route's meta and show error messages on the data loading failure. On success it shows the original route's component (stored in the route's meta too).